# How to replace an empty selector inside the underscorejs template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have 2 backbone nested views that render a table of products for a shopping cart.
Every view has its own underscore template. When the cart is empty only the main view will render replacing the empty div with: "cart is empty". Unfortunately the following solution didn't work:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <table class="standard-table">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                    <th>Product code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>                  
            </thead>
          <tbody class="cart-table-body">       

          <% if (typeof(product_id)=="undefined") { %>
               <tr>
                  <td>cart is empty</td>                
               </tr>   
          <% } %>

         </tbody>

        </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

The nested template

```
    <td><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></td>
    <td><%= product_id %></td>
    <td><%= product_name %></td>
    <td><%= price %></td>
    <td><%= quantity %></td>
    <td><%= price*quantity %></td>
```

Comment: Could you also add js code of `addProduct` and `render` (or similar) methods of your cart view.

Comment: @zaquest: I found this solution in the Backbone main view: `if (!this.collection.length){
this.$(".cart-table-body").html('<th colspan="6">the cart is empty</th>')
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you never pass `product_id` into the first template, meaning it always shows `cart is empty`. You should pass there some flag variable like `products_length` or `empty_cart` so the template could check if cart is empty.

Also with this approach you need a way to check whether you add first product and in that case replace existing innards of `cart-table-body` (`cart is empty` message) with a first added product view element. Then append views of following elements.